# Order List of Objects C ; field by choice

Tags: c++, list, sorting, object

after a lot of research and attemptings to resolve this problem

I wanted to know if there's a way to order a List of Objects in C++ ;

all the solutions I've seen so far , we have to previously define which camp will be used for the sorting.

What I wanted was the liberty for the user to choose which camp he wants to use to sort here's my code

```
class LOL
{
   public:
   LOL( const string& Nickname = "", int skill = 0,int level= 0 );
   bool operator > ( const LOL &rhs ) const; 
   void print() const;

   private:
   int level_;
   string Nickname_;
   int skill_;
};

inline
LOL::LOL( const string& Nickname, int skill, int level)
   : level_( level), Nickname_( Nickname ), skill_( skill )
{} 



inline
bool LOL::operator > ( const LOL& rhs ) const
{ return Nickname_  > rhs.Nickname_; } 



inline
void LOL::print() const
{ cout << Nickname_ << " from level " << level_
   << " has skill of [ " << skill_ <<" ]"<< endl<< endl;
}

int main( )
{
   list<LOL> list1;
   list1.push_back( LOL( "Dhespair", 50000, 30 ) );
   list1.push_back( LOL( "Pedro", 1, 1 ) );
   list1.push_back( LOL( "Blackblood", 99999, 30 ) );
   list1.push_back( LOL( "Zladovic", 30000, 25 ) );

   list1.sort( greater <LOL>()  );
   for_each( list1.begin(), list1.end(), mem_fun_ref( &LOL::print ) );
   printf("\n\n");
   system("pause");
}
```

After a few tries I came up with this solution

```
class LOL
{
   public:
   LOL( const string& Nickname = "", int skill = 0,int level= 0 , int op=1);
   bool operator > ( const LOL &rhs        ) const; // MUDAR O > para maior  ou < MENOR
   bool operator < ( const LOL &rhs        ) const; // MUDAR O > para maior  ou < MENOR
   void print() const;

   private:
   int level_;
   string Nickname_;
   int skill_;
   int op_;
};

inline
LOL::LOL( const string& Nickname, int skill, int level, int op)
   : level_( level), Nickname_( Nickname ), skill_( skill ), op_( op )
{} 



inline
bool LOL::operator > ( const LOL& rhs ) const
{ 
    switch(rhs.op_)
    {
    case 1:
    return Nickname_  > rhs.Nickname_; 
    break;

    case 2:
    return level_  > rhs.level_; 
    break;

    case 3:
    return skill_ > rhs.skill_; 
    break;
    } // MUDAR O  > para maior  ou < MENOR e ESCOLHER CAMPO A TER EM CONTA
}

inline
bool LOL::operator < ( const LOL& rhs ) const
{ 
    switch(rhs.op_)
    {
    case 1:
    return Nickname_  < rhs.Nickname_; 
    break;

    case 2:
    return level_  < rhs.level_; 
    break;

    case 3:
    return skill_ < rhs.skill_; 
    break;
    } // MUDAR O  > para maior  ou < MENOR e ESCOLHER CAMPO A TER EM CONTA
}


inline
void LOL::print() const
{ cout << Nickname_ << " from level " << level_
   << " has skill of [ " << skill_ <<" ]"<< endl<< endl;
}

int main( )
{
   list<LOL> list1;
   list1.push_back( LOL( "Dhespair", 50000, 30,3 ) );
   list1.push_back( LOL( "Pedro", 1, 1,3 ) );
   list1.push_back( LOL( "Blackblood", 99999, 30,3) );
   list1.push_back( LOL( "Zladovic", 30000, 25,3 ) );

   list1.sort( less <LOL>()  );
   for_each( list1.begin(), list1.end(), mem_fun_ref( &LOL::print ) );
   printf("\n\n");
   system("pause");
}
```

what I did was had a new value to my object which I will use to manipulate the switch case inside the bool operator.

It works, but if someone knows a way to use that switch without having to had a new parameter in my object I would really appreeciated x)

best regards

Comment: Would a parameterized predicate, having the parameter(s) dictate the ordering based on inner-criteria, address this? The `std::less<>` and `std::greater<>`` always hit the contained-classes definitive `operator <()`, which means you *must* change what *that* means (at the operator level) if you're restricting yourself to only using  the std lib predicates. Providing your with parameters would solve your problem, but not apparently how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool compareTwoLOLObjectsWay1(LOL &A, LOL &B)
{
  /* Logic to determine if A<B */
}

bool compareTwoLOLObjectsWay2(LOL &A, LOL &B)
{
  /* Logic to determine if A>B */
}

switch(sortWay)
{
  case 1:
    list1.sort(&compareTwoLOLObjectsWay1);
    break;
  case 2:
    list1.sort(&compareTwoLOLObjectsWay2);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Whoops. You can still provide a custom `Compare` function to the list sort however, so it should still work.

Comment: thanks for the help dude, but that wasnt exactly I had in mind, I wanted to take advantage of both function "greater" and "less"

I tried another option Im going to edit now and show you how I did , and if you know how to make it better I will appreciate any tips =) best regards